# Issues Mounting NFS Server: Server Side MacOS, client side SAMA5D27 board

Tags: networking, server, mount, nfs, macosx

I am trying to mount an NFS server with the Server side being my laptop running MacOS Mojave, and the client side being my SAMA5D27 board running Ubuntu Linux built using Yocto.

I've assigned an IP address to the SAMA5D27 board, and am able to ping the SAMA5D27 board from my laptop, and vice versa. So they are visible to each other.

On my laptop, I've edited the /etc/exports file to say the following:

```
/Users/mntpnt    -network 192.168.1.8    -mask 255.255.255.0
```

I then started nfsd on the laptop by running the following commands:

```
$ sudo nfsd enable
$ sudo nfsd start

$ sudo nfsd status 
nfsd service is enabled
nfsd is running (pid 24885, 8 threads)
```

On the SAMA5D27, I run the following command (server IP: 192.168.1.8)

```
$ showmount -e 192.168.1.8
```

it shows:

```
Export list for 192.168.1.8:
/Users/mntpnt 192.168.1.8
```

I then try to do the mounting using the following command on the client SAMA5D27:

```
$ sudo mount -v -t nfs 192.168.1.8:/Users/mntpnt /mntpnt
mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu ApNF 9 00:37:14 2020S: bad mount option value specified: minorversion=1

mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=192.168.1.8,clientaddr=192.168.1.100'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,minorversion=1,addr=192.168.1.8,clientaddr=192.168.1.100'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Invalid argument
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.8,clientaddr=192.168.1.100'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=192.168.1.8'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.8 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Timed out
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.8 prog 100005 vers 3 prot TCP port 872
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.1.8:/Users/mntpnt
```

I have also tried editing the permissions in the /etc/exports so that it now reads:

```
/Users/mntpnt    -network 192.168.1.8 (rw, no_root_squash)    -mask 255.255.255.0
```

and I also did a `$ sudo nfsd restart` on my MacOS after that.

So now the access denied error on the SAMA5D27 goes away, but I'm now not getting a response at all:

```
$ sudo mount -v -t nfs 192.168.1.8:/Users/mntpnt /mntpnt
mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu Apr  9 00:45:43 2020NFS: bad mount option value specified: minorversion=1

mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=192.168.1.8,clientaddr=192.168.1.100'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,minorversion=1,addr=192.168.1.8,clientaddr=192.168.1.100'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Invalid argument
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.8,clientaddr=192.168.1.100'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=192.168.1.8'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Program not registered
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=17
```

This seems to go on in a loop until I get a connection timed out.

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Comment: Try just `sudo mount 192.168.1.8:/Users/mntpnt /mntpnt`